# Tomcat interrogation with eclipse under linux/mac

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, tomcat

I added my local tomcat 8.0.14 with eclipse successfully. My local tomcat is located at /Users/masum/tool/tomcat-8.0.14. I can see it form eclipse runtime Environment as well. Whenever I deploy any webapp to eclipse's tomcat. It doesn't appear in local tomcat-8.0.14/webapps directory. I expected it should go there. But it doesn't.

Also is I do any changes in tomcat/conf/server.xml. These changes doesn't effect in eclipse integrated tomcat. Also if local tomcat is running, port number conflicts with eclipse's tomcat. I have to stop local tomcat to work with eclipse tomcat. Looks like two different instance of tomcat.

My question is where does eclipse tomcat physically located? If I deploy any web app in eclipse  tomcat where it actually goes? How can I configure Tomcat so that I can control it both from eclipse and also manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Double click  your tomcat server in the servers tab. In the servers tab you will see "Server path" under server locations. This is the location of eclipse's tomcat working directory.  If you stop tomcat and undeploy all web apps, start and stop again, you will be able to select other options. Click "Use custom location" to set the location to a place of your choosing. In project Explorer you should see a tomcat folder.  Under that folder you will find server.xml and the other config files, which you can modify as needed.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I found Sever path:  .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0 and deploy path: wtpwebapps. But inside of wtpwebapps only dir is ROOT. There is nothing inserting inside ROOT. I have 2 web app published currently. I was expecting to see them inside wtpwebapps. Note that I tried to stop/start to see any changes. Nothing happens. Where is my published app located?